# Reading peek topic from kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic name which is `push-processing-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition` and this is internal topic by kafka. I did not create this topic and I am using `.peek()` method after repartition and using peek method 3-4 times.

My question is I can read from topic `topic read push-processing-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition`, but I can not read when I say `topic read push-processing-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition --from-beginning`.

This internal topic is created because of `peek` method right?

Or is it related with other repartition streams code, but its name is `KSTREEAM-PEEK`?

It has 50 partitions. Because of `peek` is stateless operation, it should not create internal topics right but why is it name is related with `peek` and why I can not read from beginning?

Any idea please/

Here is first topology:

```
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [appconnect_deviceIds_exported_for_push])
      --> KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000004
    Processor: KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000004 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000005
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000005 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000007
      <-- KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000004
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000007 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000005
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006 (topic: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000005-repartition)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000007

  Sub-topology: 1
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000008 (topics: [KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000005-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000009
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000028 (topics: [KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000025-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000029
    Processor: KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000009 (stores: [appconnect_device_stream-STATE-STORE-0000000001])
      --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000008
    Processor: KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000029 (stores: [appconnect_device_stream-STATE-STORE-0000000001])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000030
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000028
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000011
      <-- KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000009
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000030 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000031
      <-- KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000029
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000031 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000032
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000030
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000011 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000012
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002 (topics: [appconnect_device_stream])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000003
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000012 (topic: appconnect_devices_exported_for_push)
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000011
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000032 (topic: appconnect_devices_exported_for_push)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000031
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000003 (stores: [appconnect_device_stream-STATE-STORE-0000000001])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002

  Sub-topology: 2
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000013 (topics: [appconnect_userIds_exported_for_push])
      --> KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000017
    Processor: KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000017 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000013
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000020
      <-- KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000017
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000020 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000019
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000019 (topic: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018-repartition)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000020

  Sub-topology: 3
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000021 (topics: [KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000022
    Processor: KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000022 (stores: [appconnect_user_stream-STATE-STORE-0000000014])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000023
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000021
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000023 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000024
      <-- KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000022
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000024 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000025
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000023
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000025 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000027
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000024
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000027 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000026
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000025
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000015 (topics: [appconnect_user_stream])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000016
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000026 (topic: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000025-repartition)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000027
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000016 (stores: [appconnect_user_stream-STATE-STORE-0000000014])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000015
```

That is step two,

```
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000017 (topics: [KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000018
    Processor: KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000018 (stores: [appconnect_push_processing_submissions-STATE-STORE-0000000000])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000019
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000017
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000019 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000020
      <-- KSTREAM-JOIN-0000000018
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001 (topics: [appconnect_push_processing_submissions])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000002
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000020 (topic: appconnect_push_send_bulk)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000019
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000002 (stores: [appconnect_push_processing_submissions-STATE-STORE-0000000000])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001

  Sub-topology: 1
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000003 (topics: [appconnect_devices_exported_for_push])
      --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000007
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000007 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000008
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000003
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000008 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000010
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000007
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000010 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000008
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009 (topic: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000008-repartition)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000010

  Sub-topology: 2
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000011 (topics: [KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000008-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000012
    Processor: KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000012 (stores: [appconnect_user_stream-STATE-STORE-0000000004])
      --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000013
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000011
    Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000013 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014
      <-- KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000012
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000016
      <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000013
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000016 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000015
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000005 (topics: [appconnect_user_stream])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000006
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000015 (topic: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000016
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000006 (stores: [appconnect_user_stream-STATE-STORE-0000000004])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000005
```

And all of my these operations use same KEY. I have 5 brokers and 50 partitions for all topics. I have 10 concurrency and I scaled my app to 5. But like I said I am doing repartition and transfer data 3-4 times on a same key. That means all my values related flatMap, map operations go to same partition. 1 or 2 times I am using different key so messages distributed to different partitions, just 1-2 times. Does this affect my performance? Or I should definitely distribute on different partitions to increase my performance.

So basically is kafka showing better performance when performing join or repartition operation with 3-4 times using only a partition between the topics, because kafka will read from only and only a partition and actually knows where to read and read immediately all the data because the data on the physically parallel on the disk (I mean ssd or hdd). Or my second scenario; I should definitely use more partitions to read parallel between the partitions?

And I also think that using peek slows my process.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question and added topology

Answer (score 1):

The `peek()` operation is unrelated. Looking at the topology description you posted you program (partly) is as follows:

```java
KStream inputUser = builder.stream().flatMap().peek().filter();
KStream inputDevice = builder.stream().flatMap().peek().filter();
inputUser.join(inputDevice,...)
```

(Would be easier if you would post your code in the question, too).

Because you call `flatMap()` Kafka Streams assumes that you change the key, and hence, calling `join()` triggers the data repartitioning. The repartition topic name is generated by upstream operatore (I am not 100% sure why `PEEK` is picked instead of `FILTER` to be fair.)

> And all of my these operations use same KEY.

For this case, you might want to use `flatMapValues()` instead of `flatMap()`. For this case, Kafka Streams knows that the key did not change and thus it would not create a repartition topic.

Similarly, you might want to use `mapValues()` instead of `map()` if the key does not change to avoid unnecessary repartitioning.

> My question is I can read from topic "topic read push-processing-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition" but I can not read when I say "topic read push-processing-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition --from-beginning"

I am not sure what you mean by this. What does

> when I say "topic read push-processing-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition --from-beginning"

mean? Do you refer to the command line tool `bin/kafka-consumer.sh`? In general, yes, you can read from a repartition topic, but I am not sure why this would be useful?

Comment: Yes I mean bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <broker_host>:9092 --topic test --from-beginning. I can't read internal topics -from -beginning. According to my logic I can't use flatMapValues instead of flatMap. My operations like this. .flatMap().peek().join().map().peek().to(y topic)...And after that I am listening that y topic using kafka-streams, continious like listening y topic and doing .peek().leftJoin().selectKey().peek().join().filter().to() and my operation is done. I was worried about all of those selecting new key operations use a same key.

Comment: I can distribute my messages (about 2-3 million records) to different partitions but would it be faster against using only a partition. I am curious about RocksDB and kafka disk operations and how they work against 1 partition or multiple partitions. According to my topology; All of my data go to same partition and does KStream better job when using  1 partition or should I definetely use distributed partitions ? Because I am doing 3-4 times repartition and selecting only 1 same key. So am  I blocking the process by not distrubiting my data. I am not sure which strategy is more faster

Comment: `I can't read internal topics -from -beginning` -- what is the exact problem? What error do you get? And why would you want to do this to begin with? -- Why can't you use `flatMapValues()`? -- If you say "same key" do you mean that you don't modify the input key? Or do you mean that all message are mapped to a single key?

Comment: All message are mapped to a single key, so they all go to same partition about 2-3 million records. I must do a join operation so I can't have much options. The problem is when I say "bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <broker_host>:9092 --topic push-processing-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000014-repartition" it is okay, but when I added --from-beginning I can't read. I am curious about why I can't read from beginning internal topic.

Comment: If all messages are mapped to the same key, having multiple partitions does not help obviously, because all data must go through the same partition. Kafka Streams cannot optimize this case, because when the program is compiled, Kafka Streams does not know anything about it and hence, it will insert the repartition topic into the "plan".

Comment: Not 100% sure about why `--from-beginning` does not work -- maybe it's related to the fact that Kafka uses `deleteData()` request to purge data from this topic? Not sure. But again, don't see why you want to do this.

Comment: "having multiple partitions does not help obviously, because all data must go through the same partition. Kafka Streams cannot optimize this case" yes sir my question is, does kafka speed up my process if I distribute my data to different partitions ? I know this is not a good question but I am talking about the 2-3 times re-partition and 1-2 times join process. whole the process should move on only a partition or different partitions. I wonder about RocksDB, network cost on 3 brokers and disk cost operations, which situation would it be better for case: 1 partition or multiple partitions

Comment: `yes sir my question is, does kafka speed up my process if I distribute my data to different partitions` -- if all keys are the same, this would not happen and would also be incorrect to do. -- if you create a topic with more than 1 partitions, only 1 partitions would be used, and thus you won't see any performance improvements

Comment: Thanks for the help