# Reading internal topics from beginning for kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I just want to know can I read kafka streams internal topics such as -repartitions or -peek? I can say topic read xxxx and see all the messages at that time but I can not say topic read xxxx --from-beginning, any idea?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. Kafka Streams has `...-repartition` topics but there is nothing like `..-peek` topics. Not sure what you mean by "I can say topic read" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Sir @MatthiasJ.Sax I have moved my question and it is really important for me, could you please look my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989534/reading-peek-topic-from-kafka-streams

Comment: Why did you move you question but not just edit this one?